# Full width image inside a narrow parent

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, position

I'm trying to make a responsive, full width image work inside a narrow parent. So far, I can't clear these elements.

Javascript is ok, but fussing with the HTML isn't since it should work in a WordPress theme.

HTML:

```
<p>Visible content.</p> 

<div class="feat-img">

<a href="#">
<img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/1e1515393T2l0D3I2503/feat-img.jpg"/>
</a>

</div> 

<p>Hidden content :( </p>

</article>
```

CSS:

```
.feat-img img{
position: absolute;
width: 100% !important;
min-width: 400px;
min-height: auto;
height: auto;}

.feat-img img:empty{
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,0);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
-o-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
transform: translate(-50%, 0);}

article{
width: 50%;
margin: auto;
background:#ccc;}
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/wzvLa/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can not be don only with css, because when you set `position: absolute` to `img` it's parent no longer contain it. You can write a little javascript code to do that:

```
$('.feat-img').css({ height: $('.feat-img img').height() });
```

This way you set the height of `.feat-im` to be the same as the image in it. Don't forget to do it on `$(window).resize()` too, so it can be responsive.

Here is what I do: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzvLa/8/)

Comment: This is better, but once you expand the screen size it ends up hiding the content again

Comment: That is why I said to do it on resize too. I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wzvLa/8/

Comment: Your code make a horizontal slider on the page, so... :)

Comment: This is probably the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
html,body { margin: 0; }
.feat-img img {
  position: relative;
  width: 133.33%; /* (100% divided by article width) */
  min-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
article {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

([jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2vR7/5/))

Comment: That breaks the image, it is no longer 100% width

Comment: @MathewMacLean Yes, you need to remove margins from html to get it to stretch to 100% page width. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5pz2d/)